# JQuery: обработка нажатия клавиш Enter и Tab

Tags: jquery, клавиатура, javascript

ВОПРОС РЕШЕН. Спасибо eicto!

---

Друзья, помогите разобраться, я совсем запутался

Функция проверяет формы логина/пароля.
Если логин >=3 символов и фокус на этой форме, то при нажатии на Enter или Tab должна запускаться функция flipform()

В консоли ошибок нет, flipform() сама по себе работает безотказно. Но при нажатии на  Enter или Tab flipform() срабатывает всегда только когда в форме login записано именно 3 символа. Если больше - почему-то срабатывает по двойному нажатию на Enter

У меня никаких предположений, почему такие причудливые симптомы

```
$(function() {
var login = $("input[id='frontloginform']");
var password = $("input[id='frontpasswordform']");
login.keyup(function(){
if (login.val().length>=3 && login.is(":focus")) {
    $("#enter").css("display", "block");
    $(function(){
    $("#frontloginform").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13){
            //password.focus(); - если раскомментировать, то двойного нажатия не получится, и совсем работать не будет
            flipform();
        }
        else if (e.which == 9){
        flipform();
        }
    });
    });
}
else{
    $("#enter").css("display", "none");
}
});
password.keyup(function(){
if (password.val().length>5) {
    $("#secondenter").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $("#secondenter").css("display", "none");
}
});
});
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь! Все заработало.

Про проверку полностью с вами согласен, однако тут такой дизайн, форма пароля появляется только после ввода логина :) Никаких кнопок нет

Comment: так событие submit по enter вызывается.

Comment: Тут такой дизайн, что после набора трех симоволов нужно рядом с формой показывать моргающую гифку Enter, чтобы человек догадался ее нажать после окончания набора логина :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A зачем у вас блок который вешает keydown на `#frontloginform` находится внутри обработчика login.keyup ? мне кажется это приведет к тому, что вы повесите keydown столько раз, сколько нажмете кнопок в login(после 3-го символа). кроме того, обработчик никуда не денется, если вы уменьшите длину строки до 2х.  сделайте fiddle с разметкой и примером (хотя-бы простым `flipform()`)

**Обновление**

Да я же вам говорю - вешать обработчик таким образом - ошибка, какая ещё css анимация ?

**Обновление**

Чем вас [это](http://jsfiddle.net/k3r5s/1/) не устраивает ?, но вообще проверку лучше не так делать, а по событию submit (ну и можно по переключению фокуса на инпутах)

Comment: Внутри  keyup я подсчитываю кол-во символов, которые введены

А keydown - для отслеживания нажатия Enter/Tab

На фиддле работает - http://jsfiddle.net/k3r5s/
Но банальная смена фона и на странице работает, а вот css3 анимация - с выше указанными проблемами

Comment: Обновил фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4aX/
Если ввести в форму "123" - срабатывает сразу, если "1234" - только после двойного нажатия Enter

Ок, спасибо, буду думать как его вешать по-другому